# SQL Server: Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 on historical records

Tags: sql-server, scd, scd2

I am trying to set up a SCD of Type 2 for historical records within my Customer table. [Attached is how the Customer table is set up alongside the expected outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u2rf.png) Note that the Customer table in practice has 2 million distinct Customer IDs. I tried to use the query below, but the Start_Date and End_Date are repeating for each row.

```
 SELECT t.Customer_ID, t.Lifecyle_ID, t.Date As Start_Date,
 LEAD(t.Date) OVER (ORDER BY t.Date) AS End_Date
 FROM Customer AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a three step query is likely needed.

1. Use LEAD and LAG, partitioned by Customer and ordered by date, to peek at the next row's values for both Date and Lifecycle.
2. Use a CASE statement to emit a value for End Date when the current row's Lifecycle <> the next row's lifecycle (otherwise emit NULL).  Now do the same using LAG for the Effective Date.
3. Group By or Distinct on the output from Step #2.

Hopefully that makes sense.  I'll try to post a code example later today, but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks - the issue with using distinct is that the Lifecycle_ID for Customer 123 goes from 4 to 3 and then back to 4. The distinct statement will not pick this up.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I think a different approach is likely needed.  I've edited my original post.

Comment: Thanks. 1) I am able to use LEAD to obtain the next row's Date and Lifecycle. 2) I can't obtain the End Date for the first row i.e. Customer 123 on 07/01/2019. Using LAG didn't give me the correct Effective Date for the Lifecycle. For example with Customer 123 the correct Effective Date for Lifecycle 4 should be 07/01/2019, but using LAG I was getting 
18/03/2019, which is in fact the most recent date.